# How to avoid duplication of NuGet packages

Tags: .net, nuget

Is there anyway to have a central location for local copies of various NuGet packages AND have different Visual Studio solution POINT at the single copy in the central location rather than copying the NuGet package(s) into each VS solutions \packages directory ?

I know disk space is cheap, but having multiple copies of NUnit, EF, etc. just seems wasteful

Comment: 1. Disk space is cheap
2. Why is this software so bloated?

Comment: This is the default going forward with the new packagereference approach.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**No** you can't. See http://nuget.codeplex.com/workitem/215

Answer (score 2):

What happens when there is an update to a package?  Are you going to test every project with the new version of the package?

What happens when a package has a breaking change?

Having separate copies of a package per solution allows you to test and update one at a time.  This is a good thing.

Also, most packages are so small that you would need hundreds, if not thousands of copies of them to notice the "waste".

**A few examples**
EF 4.3.1 is 2.84 MB.
NUnit 2.3.012054 is 795 KB.
Unity 2.1.505 is 1.45 MB.

Stop worrying about this.  It isn't worth your time.

Comment: While I totally agree with "Stop worrying about this, it's not worth your time" I would like to point out that if there are multiple versions of a NuGet package, NuGet stores them all and updates the individual project's repositories.config. =)

Comment: @J.Steen fair enough, I was thinking when I update a package at the solution level, all the projects are also updated.  I forgot that projects in other solutions will not be impacted.  Still, this could cause confusion as to which package to use when multiple version are installed in the central location.

Comment: definitely. It only brings you more headache to even bother  with it. =)

Comment: @cadrell0 A secondary requirement is the need to have internet connectivity, which we don't always have ... thus the desire to download the package once to a local directory, and then have any new solutions use that as the source

Comment: @SteveC, Ah! But that you can solve with a local NuGet proxy. There are several articles about for that kind of thing. I simply put all my packages in a local place, pointed an extra NuGet proxy at that location, and presto.

Comment: @SteveC That is a completely different problem than the one in the one in the question.  Here is a tutorial about how to mirror NuGet packages locally.  http://weblogs.asp.net/jgalloway/archive/2011/02/02/downloading-a-local-nuget-repository-with-powershell.aspx

Comment: Also, if that is the real question.  It is a duplicate of this one.  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7582610/use-nuget-on-an-intranet.  I'm not going to flag the question as a duplicate, because as it is currently written, it is not.

Comment: Why is that having a single local copy of packages in filesystem affecting independent solutions/projects? I don't think OP meant to share the same exact version across solutions. Anyway the default today is having a central cache (usually in `/user/.nuget` folder) which makes OP's question all the more valid.

Answer (score 1):

**Yes**, this is entirely possible now since NuGet 2.1.

1. You need to move your NuGet.config file to a central location.
2. Change the `repositoryPath` configuration value to specify the central location for all your packages ([NuGet docs](http://docs.nuget.org/docs/reference/nuget-config-settings)).
3. Do some hacking in the targets file to remove the `solutionDir` option from the restore command.
4. Update all your project references to point to the new location.

To avoid duplication, I've gone into a little more detail on exactly what to do in this answer: https://stackoverflow.com/a/19466173/564726