# How can I specify one central place where all the nuget packages will be installed

Tags: nuget

How can I specify one central place where all the nuget packages will be installed, so that all projects can refer to the same packages folder.

When 1 project have delete the reference does not depends on another project. so I can easily update the new version nuget in a single folder and works on all.

It will also save disk space in source control.

Can someone give me any suggestions?

Comment: You can use [package restore](http://docs.nuget.org/docs/workflows/using-nuget-without-committing-packages) and never commit packages to source control

Comment: See also ... http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11295458/how-to-avoid-duplication-of-nuget-packages/19466230?noredirect=1#19466230

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can specify where the packages folder should be placed (or change the name of it) via the nuget.config file.

See: [NuGet Configuration Settings](http://docs.nuget.org/docs/reference/nuget-config-settings) or [Specify ‘packages’ Folder Location](http://docs.nuget.org/docs/Release-Notes/NuGet-2.1#Specify_%e2%80%98packages%e2%80%99_Folder_Location)

Comment: i tried but i wouldn't work in visual studio 2010? can someone give the full details to how it will work in nuget 2.1 with visual studio?

Comment: yes, it works in 2010. but when i enable restore package options in the solutions and then rebuild the package will restore the default package directory.how to set the shared path in this scenario's also?

Answer (score 3):

There are in fact two steps to restoring packages to a different location correctly. Assuming you used Visual Studio (right-click on solution -> Enable package restore) you will have a *.nuget* directory in the same directory your solution resides. You need to edit two files to get this right.

Edit **NuGet.Config**
Add the repository path setting as specified in the [documentation](http://docs.nuget.org/docs/reference/nuget-config-settings).

```
<configuration>
  <solution>
    <add key="disableSourceControlIntegration" value="true" />
  </solution>
  <config>
    <add key="repositorypath" value="..\..\packages" />
  </config>
</configuration>
```

..\packages will mimic the default behavior. The **path is relative to the project folder** (not the .nuget folder) so ....\ will be the directory up from your project files.

If your projects are really all over the place, consider moving the **Nuget.config** file to the root of your source tree and configure the `repositryPath` relative to that location instead. You can of course use full paths as well but that's ugly.

Secondly, you need to remove the `solutionDir` option from the restore command (they don't tell you to do this anywhere). For that, edit **NuGet.targets**

Look for the `RestoreCommand` element and remove the `solutionDir` argument.

From this: `<RestoreCommand>$(NuGetCommand) install "$(PackagesConfig)" -source "$(PackageSources)"  $(NonInteractiveSwitch) $(RequireConsentSwitch) -solutionDir $(PaddedSolutionDir)</RestoreCommand>`

To this: `<RestoreCommand>$(NuGetCommand) install "$(PackagesConfig)" -source "$(PackageSources)"  $(NonInteractiveSwitch) $(RequireConsentSwitch)</RestoreCommand>`

Depending on what version of Visual Studio you generated the files with, the actual XML could be different than my example. Just make sure that option is removed and leave everything else the same.

**NB**: Now that you have changed the location of the packages directory (or even names it something else) you will need to update your project references to point to the new location. Relative paths are obviously recommended. You can do this manually in Visual Studio (painful) or open up the .csproj/.vbproj files and find/replace the `HintPath` for the reference.

Comment: Thanks for the detailed instructions.  Tried all the steps but still could not get this working.  If I move NuGet.config to say c:\dev\src, and set repositoryPath value to ..\packages, should I expect a folder in c:\dev\packages?

Comment: @KlausNji, I don't think it's going to work if you put the config in the src directory. It needs to be in the root (C:\dev). As mentioned, the path is relative to the PROJECT, not where your Nuget.config file lives. So if you use ..\packages and you project is in C:\dev\src\myproject\myproject.csproj, then it will end up in C:\dev\src.

Comment: Thanks, It helped me. I was trying to fix errors related to this from 2 hours. With this solution it got fixed. :)

Answer (score 0):

Here is complete description on what we have done:
[Force a reference to be absolute using Visual Studio](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/812603/force-a-reference-to-be-absolute-using-visual-studio/69881993#69881993)

In summery:

1. Each developer created a single direcrory to store all packages from all solutions.
2. Then create virtual drive letter in their machine point to that directory.
3. Modify global nuget.config at %Appdata%\NuGet\NuGet.Config to use new location
4. Reinstall packages to change HintPath in .csproj files
5. Push changes to source control.